# How to implement conversion between two third party types?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion

I'm using two independent third party libraries in my C++ project (Qt, cocos2d). Both define their own version of 2d and 3d vectors. How could I implement custom implicit (or explicit) conversion methods, so that I don't have to explicitly create new instances like this:

```
// mousePosition is of type QPointF
auto position = cocos2d::Vec2(mousePosition.x(), mousePosition.y())
```

Of course I cannot really modify the source of either library. In Obj-C or C# I could use class extensions. I'm not sure about C++. Is there any better solution than plain global functions?

Comment: You could create your own custom vector type that would include conversion operator that would return the correct types (based on what you are assigning to)

Comment: There is a great article about user-defined conversion: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: You could write a function to encapsulate the internal details. You could overload that function by parameter so you don't pollute the namespace.

Comment: As @UnholySheep suggests, you could implement your own intermediate class, and have have implicit convert methods through your intermediate. Alternatively, your intermediate could be a lightweight owner wrapper around whichever one it sees first, with convert methods, so you don't pay for the conversion when you don't need it. Probably not worth it for a limited number of dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no way to implement an *implicit* conversion between two types without altering either of them.  This can be explained mechanically: such a conversion would have to be a constructor or a conversion operator, both of which must be members.

The more enlightening explanation is that such an implicit conversion could break existing use of the types (*e.g.*, by introducing ambiguity).  With templates, it can easily be undefined behavior to introduce additional overloads (or, in this hypothetical case, make more viable) after the template is defined.

So your conversion must be explicit, and then it’s trivial: define

```
B convert(const A&);
A convert(const B&);
```

for as many `A`-`B` pairs as necessary; conveniently, they need not even have different names, since by hypothesis there is no implicit conversion between them.